# Teutonic for the thing, Romance for the reflection

Tags: etymology, history, philosophy, germanic-vs-latinate-vocabulary

In the first chapter of Capital on page 126 (1990 Penguin Edition), a footnote is attached to the sentence, "The usefulness of a thing makes it a use-value."

> In English writers of the seventeenth century we still often find the word 'worth' used for use-value and 'value' for exchange-value. This is quite in accordance with the spirit of a language that likes to use a Teutonic word for the actual thing, and a Romance word for its reflection.

Is this an actual linguistic phenomenon of English, and is it well-known? If so, what are some resources that I could read more about this?

The distinction between a "thing" and its "reflection" is a bit vague, so I'm not sure any example I could come up with would actually fit this observation. I found [this Wikipedia list of Germanic and Latinate equivalences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Germanic_and_Latinate_equivalents_in_English), but it doesn't seem particularly helpful in finding examples of this type.

Comment: Because English is essentially a Germanic language.. [In general, English words that come from German tend to be **basic, everyday words** that people say and hear very regularly. On the other hand, it tends to be the case that English words of Latin descent are perceived as more sophisticated, or having a more complex meaning.](https://voxy.com/blog/2013/06/german-vs-latin/) Oscar Wilde said *A fool is someone who knows the **price** of everything and the **value** of nothing*, which makes sense to me (value is more important than price). But which of "use-value" and "exchange-value" is best?

Comment: Is *gold* valuable because we can use it for reliable connections in electronic circuits (its "use-value"?). Or because gold "reflects" money, making it easy to convert unwanted gold jewellery into hard cash?

Comment: I think this comment is what passes for a joke in Marx. Which doesn't mean it's entirely untrue, because most jokes contain a seed of truth, but equally I wouldn't treat Marx as authoritative on the subject of philology.

Comment: @StuartF The footnote was not written by Marx.